# How do I expand this?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

In order to calculate the integral

$$
I =\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-xy}\,dx\,dy
$$

I have to expand it as an infinite sum of non-negative polynomial functions.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\dfrac{1}{1-xy}dxdy= \sum_{n=0}^∞ \int_0^1\int_0^1 (xy)^n dxdy$$
$$\implies\sum_{n=0}^∞ \int_0^1 \dfrac{y^n}{n+1}dy= \sum_{n=0}^∞ \dfrac{1}{(n+1)^2}= \dfrac{π^2}{6}$$
Generally
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1...n^{th}\dfrac{dx_1dx_1dx_3..dx_n}{1-x_1x_2..x_n}= \zeta(n)$$

Comment: Thank you so much!! That makes a lot of sense.